# Can't click on Property Page visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

Why can I not click on the property page-tab? It's disabled...

[image]

In my other project I can do it, but not in this one... And they're both ASP.

REINSTALLED VS2012 AND STILL THE SAME PROBLEM!

Comment: Have you tried closing and reopening? That solves most vs.mysteries

Comment: Yes, still the same problem...

Comment: Then I suspect your not.telling us something? Any errors or warnings? Is it all controls? Are servers involved with your project?

Comment: ????? I just created an ASP project, and added a repeater. Nothing else.

Comment: Is the runat attribute specified?

Comment: @RameezAhmedSayad Yes it is

Comment: I am going to reinstall VS 2012.... Let's check if it works.

Comment: But are you getting Intellisense if you manually type in the properties?

Answer (score 1):

I think that your problem is for Repeater control. If you delete your Repeater control from your web form and rerun your solution, it may be resolve.

In some cases, this problem is for some add-ons. So, you can disable your add-ons and then, it may be solve after rerunning your solution.

You can check the following links:

[VS2012: Property Pages isn't opening: Object reference not set to an instance of an object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12525354/1625883)

[Cannot open Property Pages for solution](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/763961/cannot-open-property-pages-for-solution)