# Right click 'Properties' on VS2012 solution displays: "Object not set to instance of an object" error

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nservicebus, t4scaffolding

Started receiving the "Object reference not set to instance of an object" error when trying to view the properties dialog for a solution in VS2012 after upgrading from NServiceBus v3 to v4.

The problem looks like it's the same as raised in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12525354/vs2012-property-pages-isnt-opening-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of), so sorry for any duplication.  This post was raised nearly a year ago and I'm hoping some others in the NServiceBus community may have found a solution.

Pretty sure the offender is the T4Scaffolding.Core library (as suggested by kevin_fitz in the above post) that NServiceBus 4 depends on.  If I uninstall NServiceBus, the issue goes away - but that then presents a number of other problems :)  NuGet won't let me uninstall the T4Scaffolding.Core as NServiceBus depends on it.

Any help greatly appreciated!  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm having the same issue if you have a solution, however mine is with MVC-4 asp.net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13453109/error-when-clicking-on-solution-properties-object-reference-not-set-to-an-in) works, if you cannot disable any extensions then make sure there all *up-todate*. I found that if you uninstall **ANY** extension in my case `BOEditor` the issue will **resolve**. You can install them back after the uninstall.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, Don. This does work to a point - if I uninstall an arbitrary extension then the solution properties will display.  But the issue does return (not sure what makes it come back, it just seems to randomly start happening again). My solution has been to pick an extension I don't need, install it and then uninstall it when the problem comes back. I'll then re-install it so I can uninstall it when the problem starts happening again.  Not great, but I can live with it for now!

Comment: `Not great, but I can live with it for now!` -- until windows decides to fix the bug :) - wich hopefully is soon