# Visual Studio Error: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" when clicking on a project and opening Properties

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have a weird behavior of Visual Studio 2013 (and 2010), that i cant seem to fix.

I know this is not directly related to programming (similar questions achieve the same error message via code, so i assume it is code within VisualStudio that has a problem).

My projects are C++.

Whenever i click on a project and open its properties, i get the following error box:

[image: Error Message]

with the text:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I can trigger that error message by selecting "Configuration Properties -> General". The view then does not show the information for "General".

My setting is the following: Windows 7 Enterprise SP1 64bit, Visual Studio 2010 (i need the compiler) and Visual Studio 2013 Professional (Update 4).

I have to work with these extensions:

- IBM Clearcase Integration
- IBM RTC VS Integration
- Visual Assist X
- Xoreax Incredibuild

What i did try without success:

- Remove all VS related files/folders in

  - `%APPDATA%\..\Local\Microsoft`
  - `%APPDATA%\..\Roaming\Microsoft`
  - `%PROGRAMFILES%`
  - `%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%`
  - `%USERPROFILE%\Documents`
- Repair/Reinstall VS2010 and VS2013 (i always installed VS2010 first)
- Reinstall .NET Framework 4.5.2
- Create a new project from within VS2013, i get the usual error plus:[image: new_proj_error]
- Use TotalUninstaller as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28050106/875020) to remove all extensions
- Hooking into the devenv process with WinDBG did not work (in non-invasive i couldnt get it to run)
- Start devenv.exe with [safemode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241278.aspx) and [log](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241272.aspx)
- Uninstall NuGet as proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17312698/875020)
- Create new solution and delete old .suo and .sdf files
- Look at output [image: output] of [ProcMon](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896645.aspx) while triggering the error. I checked the registry for that key: nonexistent
- Look at [logfile](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2e32538548fcbf10c204) at `%APPDATA%\..\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ActivityLog.xml` generated via /log: the keys are found within other keys of the value "(Default)". No clue on how to interpret that
- Reset all user settings via the (also secret) options named [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19460071/875020)
- Run .NET [Fixing Tools](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2698555) and [SFC](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/929833)
- Clean (remove from) registry

  - `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\`
  - `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\`

So my questions are

- How could i further debug the problem
- How can i really delete/reset all user settings and files and cleanup the registry
- Could this be related to solutions or projects
- Any third party components known to be problematic? .Net Frameworks?

Comment: Related (possible duplicate): [Error when clicking on Solution -> Properties (Object reference not set to an instance of an object)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13453109/error-when-clicking-on-solution-properties-object-reference-not-set-to-an-in)

Comment: thanks! how did i not find this before

Comment: There's another one: [VS2012: Property Pages isn't opening: Object reference not set to an instance of an object](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12525354/96780). I googled: whenever i click on a project and open its properties object reference not set to an instance of an object. I will edit your question title, so that the relevant part "Whenever i click on a project and open its properties" appears on it.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, they all seem to be resolved with "disable/uninstall nuget", which doesnt work for me. Also, i am facing the problem when looking at the generals tab of the project properties, not the solution. Though i have no clue if that does matter in the end.

Comment: Starting in safe mode didn't give any results whatsoever? That's strange. Maybe I'd just try uninstalling everything and installing it again. Does this happen from day one? After a clean install and in a "hello world" project, this should not happen. If it did happen, maybe I'd return Visual Studio and ask for my money back.

Comment: Yep, uninstalled "everything", happens after a clean install while creating a new project. Because of this behaviour, i assume its a central/shared resources that went bonkers. I removed all the SQL things (somewhat related to intellisense) as well as .Net Framework (4.5.1) prior reinstalling. I have been living some months with the problem, so i cannot say what triggered it :/

Comment: i ended up reinstalling windows, the good news: the problem is gone

Comment: In some weird behavior cases of Visual Studio like:
- suddenly collapsing
- unclear message box thrown directly from IDE
- being freez for a while with no special reason
I delete the *.suo file from the location where the solution file is. It usually helped me.

Comment: @DamianKobak it happened on completely new projects as well